# Label is attached to the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

How to add a block with the send button so that it moves with the keyboard. And also that would be textview behaved the same.

**preview**

[image]

Comment: send buton - its your tool bar or else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your controller

```
func createInputAccessoryView () -> UIToolbar {

        let toolbarAccessoryView = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 44))
        toolbarAccessoryView.barStyle = .default
        toolbarAccessoryView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.flexibleSpace, target:nil, action:nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:.done, target:self, action:Selector(("doneTouched")))
        toolbarAccessoryView.setItems([flexSpace, doneButton], animated: false)

        return toolbarAccessoryView
    }

    @objc func doneTouched() {
        /* Your action goes here */
    }
```

Now add this in your viewDidLoad or anywhere

```
yourTextView.inputAccessoryView = createInputAccessoryView ()
```

Comment: The last line gives: Expression resolves to an unused l-value

Answer (score 0):

Design the block view and then attach it's bottom constraint as IBOutlet and do this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()            
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)    
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {        
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        self.viewBotCon.constant = -1 * keyboardSize.height

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }        
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

      self.viewBotCon.constant = 0

      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```